# D language - Thread vs spawn

Tags: multithreading, d

I am trying to get into programming with D and I have come across something of a problem.  I started off using the core.thread Thread class which provides support for starting a thread and then joining the current thread to it.  D seems to want people to use message passing instead of lock/synchronization methods so I thought I'd give it a try, but every example of message passing I see needs the tid which I can't seem to get from the Thread class.  The code examples I see online actually use spawn which returns the tid instead of using the Thread wrapper, and then you use the tid to pass messages to the Thread.  But now there doesn't seem to be any way to join to a thread based on its tid!  And not only that but you don't seem to be able to spawn off a delegate, which requires me to add an unnecessary level of indirection.

So my question is first of all, why are there two completely different flavors of threading?  And second of all, why are they both so incomplete when together they provide basically everything you could need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`core.thread` provides the basic, low-level primitives for threading. `std.concurrency` uses `core.thread` internally. A `tid` can only be gotten from `std.concurrency.spawn`.

> So my question is first of all, why are there two completely different flavors of threading?

You might as well ask, why are there two ways to write code, normal D and inline assembly code. There's high(er) level and low level.

> And second of all, why are they both so incomplete when together they provide basically everything you could need?

They're not incomplete, but your multithreading must be designed to work in one or the other. If `std.concurrency` allowed arbitrary access to `Thread`s and such, the guarantees it makes might not be so strong.

To answer your more specific questions, it takes a `function` and not a `delegate` because a `delegate` takes a context pointer, which allows for mutation, which would break some of `std.concurrency`'s assumptions. Note that `spawn` doesn't allow *arguments* that have mutable indirection, so the no delegates thing shouldn't be shocking.

And instead of joining, you'd send a "stop" message to your thread. Again, this is higher level, and uses higher level constructs.

Comment: Well how would I tell when a thread has ended then?  Just say you have a main which isn't doing anything and another thread which is running.  Normally I would just have main call thread.join().  How would I do the same thing through message passing since main is the default thread and doesn't have a tid, therefore can't receive any messages?

Comment: Use `receive` or `receiveOnly`.

Comment: @Floss send a `Stopped` struct when the task is done and do a recieveOnly on it, also `thisTid` will give you the tid of the current thread even if it doesn't exist yet (including the main thread and any thread started with `Thread.start`)

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks that makes sense.  From Bernard's original explanation I was assuming that only threads started with spawn could receive messages.

Comment: @Floss, I never got to turning these into tutorials, but here is concurrency: https://gist.github.com/773979 and parallelism (when it was parallelfuture: https://gist.github.com/774983